# actually im trying to implement a Pinch-to-zoom functionality with panning gesture in maui blazor application

Tags: asp.net, maui-blazor

I have implemented pinch-to-zoom with panning gesture,its working as expected but pinch-to-zoom and panning gestures are not completely hapenning on whole image.

i have done pinch-to-zoom and panning gesture but its not working for entire image.

PinchTOzoom.razor:the html part of pinch-to-zoom goes here with some css styling...

```
<h3>Zoom</h3>

<div id="container" class="navBodySection" style="width:900px; height:75vh">
    <div @ref="elementRef" @onmousedown="@OnMouseDown" @onmousemove="@OnMouseMove" @onmouseup="@OnMouseUp">
        <div @ontouchmove="HandleTouchMove" @ondblclick="HandleDoubleClick">
            <img src="./Nature.jpg" class="mx-auto d-block img-fluid" style="@GetContentStyle(); height:35%; width:40%" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
    #container {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 20px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

        #container img {
            display: block;
            transition: transform .4s;
        }

        #container:hover img {
            transform: scale(1.3);
            transform-origin: 50% 50%;
        }
</style>
```

PinchTOzoom.razor.cs:Code-behide Implementation...

```
@code
{
  //PAN Gesture Start
   
 private ElementReference elementRef;
    private bool isPanning;
    private double startX;
    private double startY;
    private double translateX;
    private double translateY;

    private async Task OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        isPanning = true;
        startX = e.ClientX;
        startY = e.ClientY;
        await elementRef.FocusAsync(); 
    }

    private async Task OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isPanning)
        {
            var deltaX = e.ClientX - startX;
            var deltaY = e.ClientY - startY;

            translateX += deltaX;
            translateY += deltaY;

            startX = e.ClientX;
            startY = e.ClientY;

            isPanning = false;
            await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Alert", "Element Ref", "Ok");
        }
    }

    private void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        isPanning = false;
    }

    //PAN Gesture End

    //Pinch - To - Zoom Start
    private double currentScale = 1.0;
    private double minScale = 1.0;
    private double maxScale = 5.0;

    private double initialDistance = 0.0;
    private double initialScale = 0.0;

    private void HandleTouchMove(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Touches.Length < 2)
            return;
        var touch1 = e.Touches[0];
        var touch2 = e.Touches[1];

       
        var currentDistance = Math.Sqrt(
        Math.Pow(touch2.ClientX - touch1.ClientX, 2) +
        Math.Pow(touch2.ClientY - touch1.ClientY, 2));
        if (initialDistance == 0)
        {
         
            initialDistance = currentDistance;
            initialScale = currentScale;
        }
        else
        {
 
            var scaleFactor = currentDistance / initialDistance;
            var newScale = initialScale * scaleFactor;
            currentScale = Math.Clamp(newScale, minScale, maxScale);
        }

    }

    private bool doubleClickFlag = false;
    private void HandleDoubleClick(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        currentScale = (currentScale == minScale) ? maxScale : minScale;
       // App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Double-click occurred! ", "Working", "Ok");

    }

   private string GetContentStyle()
    {
        return $"transform: scale({currentScale});";
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested the code you provide and it worked well. You mentioned that its not working for entire image can you provide more information about this situation?